# How can I horizontally center an svg grouped circle (two paths)?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a html document showing a svg circle. Its not a real svg circle, but it is build from two paths. See below. 
See also https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmomBg

Problem:
I want to center this object in the browser winodw. StackFlow gives some solutions, using variations on `style="margin: 0 auto;"`. However, it seems that only works well for certain (simpler ?) svg images. The svg that I use, results in centering the left part of circle only, not the full circle. The codepen shows my problem visually.

HTML

```
<div class="c-container" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <svg id="yeah" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path id="bg" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#212b37" fill="none" d="M50 2 
       a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
       a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
    </path>
    <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#7bdccd" fill="none" d="M50 2 
       a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
       a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background: #1c222e;
  padding: 30px;
}
.c-container {
  width: 100px;
  svg {
    width: 500%;
  }
}
```

Comment: remove 100px and replace it with 500px then remove 500% ... (500% of 100px will be 500px)

Comment: Use this css instead: `body{
  background: #1c222e;
  padding: 30px;
}
.c-container {
  width: 500px;
  svg {
    /*width: 500%;*/  
  }
}`  The SVG will take all the width available

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `width: 500%` on your svg.

Your container should have a `width` of some value, and `margin-left` & `margin-right` of `auto`. This will make sure it is centered.

Given that the SVG doesn't have it's own `width` or `height`, it will scale to 100% of it's parent container.

So let the container do the scaling, allow the SVG to be scaled by its container.

```css
body {
  background: #1c222e;
  padding: 30px;
}

.c-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.c-container-500 {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.c-container-100 {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-container c-container-500">
  <svg id="yeah" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <path id="bg" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#212b37" fill="none" d="M50 2 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
        </path>
        <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#7bdccd" fill="none" d="M50 2 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="c-container c-container-100">
  <svg id="yeah" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <path id="bg" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#212b37" fill="none" d="M50 2 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
        </path>
        <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="4" stroke="#7bdccd" fill="none" d="M50 2 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 96 
           a 48 48 0 0 1 0 -96">
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/dwxzGG)